# Desativar Lazy Loading para uma query especifica

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com um problema de lentidão no momento de trazer os dados.

Possuo na tabela 16 mil registros que estão levando cerca de 6 segundos para serem trazidos do banco.

Notei que ao trazer estes registros esta sendo trago também os registros relacionados devido ao *lazy loading*. Porém, nesta *query* em especifico não ha necessidade de trazer os registros relacionados.

Acho que poderia ganhar algum tempo se eu não trazer estes registros desnecessários, segue o código:

```
public IList<NotaMercadoria> GetAll(long pIdCadEmpresa)
{
    return entity.NotaMercadoria.Where(x => x.IDCadEmpresa == pIdCadEmpresa).ToList();
}
```

Já que não ha necessidade de trazer os registros relacionados, existe alguma forma de desativar o *lazy loading* para esta *query* em especifica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só desativá-lo antes de buscar os dados.

```
public IList<NotaMercadoria> GetAll(long pIdCadEmpresa)
{
    entity.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = 
    entity.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return entity.NotaMercadoria.Where(x => x.IDCadEmpresa == pIdCadEmpresa).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, só me tira uma duvida, quando o Lazy Loading esta desativado ele traz a tabela relacionada mas sem nenhum dado nela, certo? Posso postar uma imagem para facilitar se achar necessário.

Comment: @Brayan É isso mesmo. O select produzido vai ser apenas na tabela principal, sem nenhum join.

Comment: Ah entendi, muito obrigado :D